# How to clear and replace the contents of an input field with the value of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

I think there is an easy solution however I have searched and cant seem to find he answer. I am trying set up several buttons that when pressed replace the the contents of an input field with the value of the button. I would prefer to control this with pure javascript rather than jquery if possible.

Also, if possible I would like the title of the button to be slightly different than the value it passes to the input field.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it

script:

```
function foo(id, el)
{
  document.getElementById(id).value = el.innerHTML.replace(/test/, 'something');
}
```

(Obviously you'd want to do something more useful to the value than replacing test by something. But you can.)

html:

```
<input id="piet"/>

<button onclick="foo('piet',this)">test123</button>
<button onclick="foo('piet',this)">test234</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sE2UV/

Answer (score 1):

Assume this markup (an extra data attribute to avoid hardcoding the selector):

```
<input id="target" type="text">
<button value="potatoes" data-for="#target">Potato</button>
<button value="tomatoes" data-for="#target">Tomato</button>
```

You may use `value` attribute to store the data:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-for]');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var targetId = buttons[i].dataset.for;
    var target = document.querySelector(targetId);

    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        target.value = this.value;
    })
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dmu8N/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script>
function setText() {
  document.getElementById("input1").value = "SOME TEXT";
}  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="setText()">Click me to set text!</button>
  <input id="input1" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Full JSBin Example: http://jsbin.com/aZIyAzir/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery solution for completeness.

```
<input type='text' id='target'></input>

<button>Merry</button>
<button>Christmas</button>
```

Then your jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var $target = $('#target');
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $target.val($(this).html());
    });
});
```